# Typescript how to do nested generic types

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to achieve something like the following:

```
type GenericPerson = {
  name: string;
};

type GenericCompany<X extends GenericPerson> = {
  companyName: string;
  employees: X[];
};

const getEmployeeDetails = <T extends GenericPerson, Company extends GenericCompany<T>>(company: Company): T[] => {
  return company.employees;
};
```

given there is no compiler warning, I assumed `getEmployeeDetails` will indeed return an array of `T`. However, when I tried the following:

```
const companyA = {
  companyName: 'XYZ',
  employees: [
    {
      name: 'John',
      address: 'London',
    },
    {
      name: 'David',
      address: 'New York',
    },
  ],
};

getEmployeeDetails(companyA).map((x) => {
  console.log(x.address);
});
```

It doesn't work at all, surprisingly `getEmployeeDetails` has a return type of `GenericPerson[]` instead.

Can someone help me on what I did wrong please? How can I achieve the desired result instead

Thanks